# want to save spinner data in sqlite database.where spinner data comes from another table

Tags: android

```
private void loadSpinnerData() 
{
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

List<String> lables = db.getAllCourt();
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public List<String> getAllCourt(){
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();


   String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_NAME_COURTTYPE + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS_COURT;

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
        labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   cursor.close();
   db.close();

return labels;
}
```

Comment: how to save spinner data can any one sugest me plz

Comment: means you want to save selected data from spinner...???

Comment: yes i want to save data which selected from spinner....in spinner items comes from another table..cau u help me....how to save?

Comment: See Kunu's answer after getting String valueOfSelectedPos you can save it as you required..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retrieve String value associated with selected position in your spinner and save that String value in your Database

```
String valueOfSelectedPos= spn.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

for adding click event on buttoms try this

```
add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.add_save_btn:

              String room = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner.label;
              dbHandler.Add_Judge(.....));
              Toast_msg = "inserted";
              break;

        case R.id.update_btn:

              String room = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner.label; 
              dbHandler.Update_Judge(.....)); dbHandler.close(); Toast_msg = "Update"; 
              break;
    }
}
```

Comment: add_address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Is_Valid_Address(add_address);
     }
 });      i am using dis way to receive data from layout after dat through database method it is save in data...... addTextChangedListener for edittext field as spinner wht will use??

Comment: String valueOfSelectedPos= spn.getSelectedItem().toString(); when we use this only first item saved all time in database...if i am selct 2nd item bt in databse first item saved............wht is d problem?

Comment: @user1960700 Select 2nd item and  print that in your logcat and let me know which item value actully showing in your logcat.

Comment: String valueOfSelectedPos= add_courttypeid.getSelectedItem().toString();dis is used widin Oncreate method bt change value stored in after oncreate method (public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
String label= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();} actually change items store in label..hw to use? help me plz

Comment: @user1960700 use this `String valueOfSelectedPos= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: yaa i use dis bt only first value save.

Comment: final String valueOfSelectedPos= add_courttypeid.getSelectedItem().toString();
 
 add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
  // check the value state is null or not
  if (valid_name != null && valid_mob_number != null
   && valid_email != null && valid_name.length() != 0
   && valid_mob_number.length() != 0
   && valid_email.length() != 0) {

      dbHandler.Add_Judge(new JudgeContact(valid_name,valid_mob_number,valid_email,valid_address,valueOfSelectedPos));
      Toast_msg = "Data inserted successfully";
     
}}

Comment: @user1960700 what is your `add_courttypeid`

Comment: Spinner add_courttypeid = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.add_court_type);

Comment: @user1960700 but in your question you have different id for you spinner
Are you using two different spinner ?

Comment: Did you print String valueOfSelectedPos ?
And if your logcat printing 1st value of spinner after selecting 2nd value then it's not problem in storing. It's problem in other part. Most probably in your spinner

Comment: @user1960700 You welcome. Can you please tell me where was the problem and how did  you solved it ?

Comment: add_courttypeid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner());  label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  after dat i was want to use dis label on my save on click listner function means  String courttype= Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner.label;
   //Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner define a cls which  implements OnItemSelectedListener 
      dbHandler.Add_Judge(new JudgeContact(valid_name,
       valid_mob_number, valid_email,valid_address,courttype));

Comment: one more questn can u help..i hv 2 onclicklistnr want to access both after oncreate method...add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(this); [add_save is worked properly] public void onClick(View v) {
   String room = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner.label;
      dbHandler.Add_Judge(.....));
      Toast_msg = "inserted";
  }                update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);[this is nt work]  public void onClick1(View v1) {
     String room = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner.label;
      dbHandler.Update_Judge(.....));
      dbHandler.close();
      Toast_msg = "Update";
          }

Comment: save my spinner data succeessfully after dat spinner data retrieve and shown in d page after dat click on edit button load spinner data in spinner and wants to update...update works bt after click on edit it loaded again only 1st data..:(

Comment: add_address.setText(c.getAddress()); its working address is a textview bt i want to set value in spinner field..after retrieve value and clicking on edit button we get spinner data in c.getCourtTypeId() now want to set dis data in spinner field for updation...wht will be use??

Comment: @user1960700 For that you have to save spinner index in database and retrieve that from your database and set it in different spinner.And ensure that both the spinner should have same data array

Comment: both screen are same when we click on save.den save button visible and update button gone.when we click edit den same screen visible bt data filled and update button visible and save button gone..another field are working properly bt spinner field not loaded.

Comment: done through setSelection add_courttypeid.setSelection(c.getCourtTypeId())..spinner data set properly....